# Why can Iterable<DeclarationMirror> not be cast to Iterable<MethodMirror>?

Tags: dart

This code does not work on the Dart VM (1.22.0-dev.9.0), but does work on DartPad (unknown version):

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Thing {
  Thing();
}

void g(ClassMirror c) {
  var constructors = c.declarations.values
      .where((d) => d is MethodMirror && d.isConstructor) as Iterable<MethodMirror>;
  print(constructors);
}

void main() {
  g(reflectClass(Thing));
}
```

Results in:

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'WhereIterable<DeclarationMirror>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<MethodMirror>' in type cast where
  WhereIterable is from dart:_internal
  DeclarationMirror is from dart:mirrors
  Iterable is from dart:core
  MethodMirror is from dart:mirrors

#0      Object._as (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:76)
#1      g (file:///google/src/cloud/srawlins/strong/google3/b.dart:9:55)
#2      main (file:///google/src/cloud/srawlins/strong/google3/b.dart:14:3)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:261)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)
```

(but in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b54c4974326cfebe1cd3c622c3511ae0) results in `(MethodMirror on 'Thing')`.)

Note that if I hand-craft some classes that implement each other, and do the same thing, it works:

```
abstract class DM {
  bool get t;
}

abstract class MM implements DM {
  MM();
  bool get t;
}

class _MM implements MM {
  bool get t => true;
}

void f(Map<dynamic, DM> dms) {
  var mms = dms.values.where((dm) => dm is MM && dm.t) as Iterable<MM>;
  print(mms);
}

void main() {
  f({1: new _MM()});
}
```

which nicely prints: `(Instance of '_MM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the iterable returned by `.where()` can only contain `MethodMirror` instances, doesn't allow the cast. The type is propagated from `c.declarations.values` which is `DeclarationMirror`. 
While you can cast a `DeclarationMirror` to a `MethodMirror`, a cast from `Iterable<DeclarationMirror>` to `Iterable<MethodMirror>` is invalid, because there is no is-a relationship between these to iterables.

It seems when built to JS by dart2js, some generic types are dropped, this is why this works in DartPad.

You can create a new `List<MethodMirror>` like

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Thing {
  Thing();
}

void g(ClassMirror c) {
  var constructors = new List<MethodMirror>.from(
      c.declarations.values.where((d) => d is MethodMirror && d.isConstructor));
  print(constructors);
}

void main() {
  g(reflectClass(Thing));
}
```

There is an open issue to make this easier https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27489

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and bug link!